# springrepository method getById returns null but findById return data

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am creating a object in the same transaction....later in the method I use spring data repository's getById method to get the object, it returns null, but when I use findById it returns the object.

why is it happening?

```
 @Transactional
    public void saveScanResultsForScan(ScanResult scanResult, Long scanId) {

        -----some---code----
       transientObject = create the object....
       apiScanRespository.save(transientObject);
       -----some-----code------

       apiScanRespository.getById(transientObject.getId()) -- this returns null

     apiScanRespository.findById(transientObject.getId()) -- this returns the object

    }
```

Comment: Where is `getById`? it doesn't appear to be part spring repository interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no getById method in Spring Data JPA. Check this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

You might have apiScanRespositoryImpl class which just returns null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we added a method getById in our repo.

The issue is resolved, it was a databse issue wherein the data was not getting saved in parent table....we had not set correct schema...So while retreving we were not getting the result... It is fixed now.

Comment: great! happy to help.

Comment: I took a look at the link written as a reference. There is method signature getById() clearly in. I encountered the same issue. the repository returns an entity by findById() but returns null by ById().